# Manga/webtoon where the protagonist is a demon who feeds on emotions

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, demons

I'm kind of sure it was a webtoon as it was based in Korea.

The protagonist was a demon and so were his friends. These demons did drink blood, but they mainly fed on emotions. One of them fed on jealousy, the protagonist fed on pride. When he saw or felt jealousy within someone around him, his hunger shrank.  So if there was no one jealous, he'd die of hunger.

The story started out with the protagonist having a car accident. Since he's a demon, the scars didn't last long.

The demons had attraction abilities via different body parts too! One of them could attract someone by using hands; if he touched them then they'd fall for him (no matter age or gender). The protagonist's attraction was via his eyes; anyone who made eye contact with him would fall for him.

Since the protagonist had that accident, he had to take the subway to his work. He didn't like taking the subway, he **hated** it.  He met a girl and they made eye contact but that girl didn't fall for him, which made him **really** suspicious. He went to his work, he was a plastic surgeon, and coincidentally the appointment he had was with the girl he met on subway. She wanted a **breast implant**.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember what site you found it on?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: actually, i jus forgot the name haha but now i know it, thank you ig hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[Call Me the Devil](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/tuw2tro/call-me-the-devil)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> **Like other devils of his kind, Hyeonshin has adapted to the modern world to consume the Deadly Sin, Pride. Working as a plastic surgeon means there's always more than enough ego around him to feed off of.** There's just one small problem: because of past trauma, he has an overwhelming repulsion toward blood! Luckily, a solution appears in the form of a plucky human named Ina, whose eyes seem to have the mysterious effect of alleviating this condition. Knowing that she's desperate to book a surgery at his busy clinic, Hyeonshin agrees to operate on her if she helps him with his "blood tolerance experiments." But due to their clashing personalities and constant interruptions from his devil coworkers, Hyeonshin's recovery seems far away. Will the devil and human both be able to attain what they truly desire?

In this world, devils have evolved to look like attractive humans, and live in secret among them, feeding on their desires. The protagonist, Hyeonshin, is a plastic surgeon and feeds on pride.

At the beginning of the story, Hyeonshin has recently wrecked his car in an accident, and is now taking the subway to work. Hyeonshin's eyes have a special power, whereby anyone who makes direct eye contact with him would normally fall in love with him, but on the subway, he meets and briefly converses with a young woman who seems immune to this effect.

Later that day, he arrives at work, and it turns out that the same woman is to be a client of his, seeking breast augmentation surgery.

You can read the first three chapters for free at [Tappytoon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/comics/call-me-the-devil).